# jQuery tab pagination questions

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

I'm a newbie to jQuery.

I've been experimenting and working on a method of using a dropdown menu to dynamically create tabs and paginate them (no need for the tabs to create a new line as seen on the default jQuery tabs plugin) but have run into a few problems which i'm not sure how to resolve. for each difficulty I have included screen shot as a visual aid.

Here is the interface its rather simple but in the future the data used within it will be dynamic.

[image]

Now here are the problems I am currently facing due to a lack of skill.

1) the title of the tab is selected from a dropdown but I'm not sure how to set individual content for each tab created. Right now each tab created is empty as seen below.

[image]

2) I would also like to prevent the duplication of tabs. Each option on the dropdown can be selected an infinite number of times.

[image]

3) lastly I hope to move the remove button alongside each tab (floated to the right) as seen on Google Chrome/Firefox tabs.

[image]

4) I am also trying to create an option to disable the default tab from being closed

Here is the code below. It can be copied and pasted as is for viewing as all dependencies are currently stored in remote web locations!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/css/reset-fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/css/base/ui.all.css" />
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
p {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 1em;
}
em {
    font-style: italic;
}
.example {
    margin: 0 1em;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin: 5px 10px 20px 10px;
}
.ui-tabs-paging-next {
    float: right !important;
}
.ui-tabs-paging-prev, .ui-tabs-paging-next {
    background: transparent !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 1px !important;
}
#example2 .ui-tabs-paging-prev, #example2 .ui-tabs-paging-next {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-tabs-paging-prev a, .ui-tabs-paging-next a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
    /* color: #444; */ 
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs-paging-next a:hover, .ui-tabs-paging-next a:focus, .ui-tabs-paging-next a:active, .ui-tabs-paging-prev a:hover, .ui-tabs-paging-prev a:focus, .ui-tabs-paging-prev a:active {
    background: transparent;
}
.ui-tabs-paging-disabled {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/js/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/js/ui/extensions/ui.tabs.paging.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // initialize tabs with default behaviors
    jQuery('#example1').tabs();
    jQuery('#example2').tabs({ cache: true });
    jQuery('#example3').tabs({ cache: true });
    jQuery('#example4').tabs({ cache: true, selectOnAdd: true });
    jQuery('#example4').tabs('select', 21);

    // initialize paging
    function init() {
        jQuery('#example1').tabs('paging');
        jQuery('#example2').tabs('paging', { cycle: true, nextButton: 'next &gt;', prevButton: '&lt; prev' });
        jQuery('#example3').tabs('paging', { follow: true, followOnSelect: true, tabsPerPage: 5 });
        jQuery('#example4').tabs('paging', { cycle: true, follow: true, followOnSelect: true, selectOnAdd: true });
    }
    init();
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size: 75%;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/"></script><script type="text/javascript"> 
function addTab(selector, index) {
    var myTabs = jQuery(selector);

    if (index == undefined)
        index = myTabs.tabs('length');

    tabId = '#tab' + (new Date).getTime();

    myTabs.tabs('add', tabId, $('#TAB_NAME').val());

    $(tabId).load('new_tab_data.txt');
}

function removeTab(selector, index) {
    var myTabs = jQuery(selector);

    if (index == undefined || index.length == 0)
        index = myTabs.tabs('length') - 1;
    else 
        index = parseInt(index);

    myTabs.tabs('remove', index)
}
</script>
<div class="example">
  <div>
  <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 30px"><select id="TAB_NAME">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
          <button onclick="addTab('#example4');">Add</button>
          </p></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 30px" valign="top"><button onclick="removeTab('#example4', jQuery('#TAB_INDEX').val());">Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
</div>
  <div id="example4">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#example4-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="example4-1">Tab 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to write a significant amount of additional code using JQuery to adapt the tabs to what you're looking for. This isn't exactly something someone can simply answer for you.

After you initialize/instantiate the jquery tabs, you'll need to then manipulate jquery's original work done in the .tabs() plugin.

I would write another plugin eg. .dynamicTabs() and incorporate the .tabs() plugin as the groundwork...

It's not a simple solution :)